# HTML/jQuery toggle() element disapears on load

Tags: jquery, html

I was writing a jQuery function which would select/unselect all checkboxes. At the moment it seemed to me as the best way to do it was using the `.toggle()` method. Unfortunately I was getting strange effect for no reason. The selected element was disappearing once the DOM was loaded. The only working solution I've found was using .show()/.fadeIn() functions. I solved the problem using `.click()` event and couple of if statements (which seemed unnecessary, if I could use `.toggle();` ). I wasn't getting any errors or warnings in the browsers developer's tools console. The first .toggle() function would fire away once the DOM is loaded. Here's the code I was using:

EDIT: oops. I've posted the wrong code. It's fixed now.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class="checkboxCheck" value="check all" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="button" class="addCheckbox" value="Add checkbox" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input:button.addCheckbox').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<br /><input type="checkbox" />');
    if($(this).prev().attr('disabled')=='disabled'){
        $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled');
    };
});

$('input:button.checkboxCheck').toggle(function(){
    alert(0);
},function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

At the point i was working on this there was no *CSS* code used at all on the website.

Why did this happen and how can avoid it in the future?

Comment: The toggle event was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 1):

Well, the toggle function was deprecated in JQuery 1.8 and removed in version 1.9. JQuery has a animation method called toggle to change elements visibility.

Selecting and deselecting all checkboxes is a common task. I'd do it like this:

```
$('.check_all').on('click', function () {
    $('.commom').prop('checked', function (i, val) {
        return !val;
    });
});
```

check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzJ43/

Comment: I'm sorry for this being a little off-topic, but doesn't it reverse the value of the checkbox? I thought of doing it this way(but with different code, but I like the way you've done it) but i needed a function that strictly checks/unchecks them all.

Comment: what do you mean with the value of the checkbox?. It selected/deselected all of the checkboxes, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm sorry, what i meant was, it reverses the state of the checkboxes(selected/unselected).

Answer (score 0):

I believe .toggle() changes the css for an element to display: none.

You said that the first .toggle() would fire when the DOM as loaded and that the element would disappear at that point. This could explain the behavior:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/